# Uploading database error

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I got the following error while uploading a database

> Error at the line 53: ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wpcads_paypal` (
 `main_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` text NOT NULL,
 `transaction_id` text NOT NULL,
 `firstname` text NOT NULL,
 `lastname` text NOT NULL,
 `email` text NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `summary` text NOT NULL,
 `created` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`main_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2
```

MySQL:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-------------------------------------------------------- -- -- CREATE TABLE IF N' at line 4
>
> Stopped on error

Comment: try removing the hyphens before Create on your query .

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this code table created success fully:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wpcads_paypal(
main_id BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
user_id TEXT NOT NULL ,
transaction_id TEXT NOT NULL ,
firstname TEXT NOT NULL ,
lastname TEXT NOT NULL ,
email TEXT NOT NULL ,
description TEXT NOT NULL ,
summary TEXT NOT NULL ,
created INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( main_id )

Answer (score 1):

no any error found in this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wpcads_paypal( main_id BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , user_id TEXT NOT NULL , transaction_id TEXT NOT NULL , firstname TEXT NOT NULL , lastname TEXT NOT NULL , email TEXT NOT NULL , description TEXT NOT NULL , summary TEXT NOT NULL , created INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( main_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a table for the same query You've mentioned 
It was fine (There is nothing wrong with your query)

The extra characters you had in your query must have been the problem, just copy the query now and try t create the table

```
mysql>  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wpcads_paypal (  main_id bigint(20)   
unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  user_id text NOT NULL,  transaction_id text NOT NULL,  firstname text NOT NULL,  
lastname text NOT NULL,  email text NOT NULL,  description text NOT NULL,  summary text NOT NULL,  created int(4) 
unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (main_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> desc wpcads_paypal;
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| main_id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id        | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_id | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname      | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname       | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email          | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description    | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| summary        | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created        | int(4) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```